# How to make a loader according to the size of the uploaded image?

Tags: css

I have chat. Inside the chat, you can share photos.

[image: chat]

in code:

```
<img alt="image" class="image" src="MyUrl">

max-width: 270px;
max-height: 270px;
border-radius: 4px
```

But I do not immediately need to insert the address of the real image, first I need to put the loader images there

```
<img alt="loader" class="image" src="https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/7plQ.gif">
```

And so how to make it so that the size is identical to what happened with the real image?

I know in advance what size the image will have, height and width. How to do this in terms of the CSS?

Comment: If you know the height and width of the image than you need to show a div with that hight and width that will have loader in the centre or where ever you want the placement to be. Because I don't know how the structure is of your HTML. Let me guess. 

<div class="img-wrapper><img realIamge /> <img loader /></div>

so add height and width to the img-wrapper and show imgloader init.

Comment: My js either shows an image or shows a loader, one of the two.

Comment: Yes that img or loader so loader can be shown the size of Image than pass that css height and width to loader as per it class name